# Using the Like '%" operator in the Sql Command Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I have a query to pull out data based on parameters, but now I have a problem using the Like '%' operator in the query, so that when I select data based on this parameter only data with the letters prefixed to this operator can be pulled.

Below is the query

```
select InventoryName,StockNumber,OBAL,RPO,XEFR,RDJ,RET,TSFR,ISS,PISS,ADJ,CBAL 
from Transactions
where InventoryName LIKE 'se%' and ReportingPeriod ='January 2005'
order by InventoryName,StockNumber
```

For example, with this I am able to pull data which has SE of January 2005. It works fine in SQL 2005 but now I want to use it in Crystal report as a parameter to help pull out data based on the InventoryName chosen and the month and year. I am new to Crystal Reports.

Comment: User a variable @input to get that parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment you may use the following :

```
where   InventoryName LIKE @input + '%'
```

Comment: @user1862899 Assuming you do have a validation to check @input is `not null`. If null you may want to set `default value` to be passed through ;) from Report level or query level.

Answer (score 0):

Use symbol '*' instead of '%'. I have encountered this problem also, sql requires '%' but CR requires '*', you can try simple example with CR designer, insert where clause in "RecordSelection".